# python 2.6 linecache.getline() and stdin. How does it work?

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.6

I have a script which runs through lines of input to find the occurrence of an ID string while keeping track of the linenumber.
Then it runs backwards up the input to trace parentID/childID relationships. The script accepts either a logfile using a '-f' flag as an argument or the contents of stdin from a pipe.
The logfile as input portion works just fine, but reading from stdin seems not to work.

For the sake of reasonable clarity I've included the portion of the script that this concerns, but don't expect to be able to run it. It's just to show you sorta whats going on (anyone who works in financial services around FIX protocol would recognize a few things):

```
import os
import sys
import linecache

from types import *
from ____ import FixMessage   # custom message class that is used throughout

# Feel free to ignore all the getArgs and validation crap
def getArgs():
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
               description='Get amendment history.')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',
               help="input logfile.'")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return validateArgs(args)


def validateArgs(args):
    try:
        if sys.stdin.isatty():
            if args.file:
                assert os.path.isfile(args.file.strip('\n')), \
                    'File "{0}" does not exist'.format(args.file)
                args.file = open(args.file, 'r')
        else:
            args.file = sys.stdin
        assert args.file, \
            "Please either include a file with '-f' or pipe some text in"
    except AssertionError as err:
        print err
        exit(1)

    return args    


defGetMessageTrail(logfile, orderId):
    # some input validation
    if isinstance(logfile, StringType):
        try: logfile = open(logfile, 'r')
        except IOError as err: exit(1)
    elif not isinstance(logfile, FileType):
        raise TypeError(
              'Expected FileType and got {0}'.format(type(logfile)))

    linenum  = 0

    # This retrieves the message containing the orderID as well as the linenum
    for line in logfile:
        linenum += 1
        if orderId in line:
            # FixMessage is a custom class that is treated here like
            # a dictionary with some metadata
            # Missing dict keys return 'None'
            # .isvalid is bool results of some text validation
            # .direction is either incoming or outgoing
            # thats all you really need to know
            msg = FixMessage(line)
            if msg.isvalid and msg.direction == 'Incoming':
                yield msg
                break

    # If there is a message parentID, it would be in msg['41']
    if msg['41']:
        messages = findParentMessages(logfile, startline=linenum, msg['41'])
        for msg in messages: yield msg



def findParentMessages(logfile, startline, targetId):
    # Some more input validation
    assert isinstance(logfile, FileType)
    assert isinstance(startline, IntType)
    assert isinstance(targetId, StringType)

    # should just make a integer decrementing generator,
    # but this is fine for the example
    for linenum in range(startline)[::-1]:
        # *** This is where the question lies... ***
        # print(logfile.name) # returns "<stdin>"
        line = linecache.getline(logfile.name, linenum)
        if 'Incoming' in line and '11=' + targetId in line:
            msg = FixMessage(line)
            yield msg
            if msg['41']: findParentMessages(logfile, linenum, msg['41'])
            else: break


def main():
    log = getArgs().file
    trail = getMessageTrail(log, 'ORDER123')


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

The question is, how does linecache.getline work when it comes to reading stdin as a file? is it different than how it would work if given a regular filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linecache.getline() accepts a file name, not a file object. It is not designed to work that way as filename is passed to calls like open() and os.stat().

For reference: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.6/Lib/linecache.py

Comment: so is it impossible then to use stdin to pipe to the script? I could make a tmp file but I dont want to!

Comment: @edaniley  I don't think it's possible with linecache. But it's much simpler to read the input with readlines() into a list of lines and use the element index as line number. linecache does the same under the hood.

Comment: the only problem I have is that these files potentially can be enormous

Comment: Then you are out of luck because linecache too reads the entire file into memory. For files on disk you could build a index and use that to seek back and forth, but stdin is a sequential read only file.

Comment: super helpful. Thank you very much!